# Galaxy S3 randomly deleting my contacts

Tags: contacts, samsung-galaxy-s-3

My Samsung Galaxy S3 just deletes some of my contacts on a regular basis.  Any ideas on how to stop this and or recover those deleted contacts?

Comment: Welcome to Android Enthusiasts! We're excited to have you here. Is this only happening to certain contacts, or is it completely random? After recreating a contact, does it later get deleted?

Comment: It just totally randomly makes the contact unknown and all the info for the contact is deleted/gone.

Answer (score 0):

Are these newly added contacts? If you are adding new contacts and adding them as "phone" contacts and not "google" contacts, and you have syncing on, it may be syncing your google contacts to your phone, and deleting the ones that aren't google contacts. This happened to me a couple of times.

Comment: Thanks but no syncing on .... :(